# Read multiple string lines

Tags: java

I am trying to read multiple lines in Java it has to be in this order. I am trying to figure out who has the most amount and display their name

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int S = input.nextInt();
        String nameS= input.nextLine();
        
        int P = input.nextInt();
        String nameP= input.nextLine();
        int E = input.nextInt();
        String nameE= input.nextLine();
        input.close();
        
        if ((S >= P) && (S >= E)){
            
            System.out.println(nameS);
        }
        else if ((P >= S) && (P >= E)){
            
            System.out.println(nameP);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(nameE);
        }
```

Comment: And why can't you? Is there an error? Please tell us that. Is there an exception? Please give us the stack trace. Is the output not what you expected? Then please give us the input, the actual output, and the expected output. Please do not handicap those who want to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty but it gets the job done for what you are trying to do and how you are trying to do it. When using nextInt() it's important to remove the new line character that gets entered right after the number is entered. In the code below you want to clear out that character after each call to nextInt() so when you want to get the name you get a string and not an empty string.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int S = input.nextInt();
 input.nextLine();//clear new line
 String nameS= input.nextLine();
 
 int P = input.nextInt();
 input.nextLine();//clear new line
 String nameP= input.nextLine();

 int E = input.nextInt();
 input.nextLine();//clear new line
 String nameE= input.nextLine();
 input.close();
 
 if ((S >= P) && (S >= E)){
     
     System.out.println(nameS);
 }
 else if ((P >= S) && (P >= E)){
     
     System.out.println(nameP);
 }
 else {
     System.out.println(nameE);
 }
```

Output

```
5
pete
45
bob
3
steve
bob
```

Here is some code to help get you started using arrays

```
 int numberOfPeople = 3;
 String[] names = new String[numberOfPeople];
 Integer[] ages = new Integer[numberOfPeople];
 
 for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++)
 {
     //hint use your logic from earlier
     //i is the index of the arrays you will assign values at
 }
```

Comment: is there any way to do it using an array?

Comment: yes you can do it with an array, you can do it with a an array of objects.. If you can show me something where you've tried using an array i will help you out. I would use two arrays, one for Integers and another for String. The int array will be the age, the string array will be the name and the index of the array would be your person. That should help you get started

Comment: @noob32467 check out my last edit at the bottom, that should give you a good jumping off point for using arrays

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with your code:

1. Each time you read input with `nextLine()`, you are assuming that there is no input buffered in the input stream or the scanner, which turns out to be a false assumption in your case

Let's take a look at your first section of code here.  I'll use this sample input:

```
1\R
Bob\R
2\R
Joe\R
3\R
Randy\R
```

Note: In this example, `\R` indicates a line separator character sequence.

Now let's see what your code does:

- You request input from your scanner, and it just started up, so it has no input buffered yet.  It reads from the input stream until it hits the first delimiter character.  This happens to be a line separator in my example.  Now the scanner's buffer is `1\R`.
- You requested an integer, so the scanner looks at its buffer and says okay, `1` is an integer.  It consumes the `1` from its buffer and returns it to you (and you store it in the `S` variable).  Now the scanner's buffer is `\R`.
- You requested more input from your scanner.  You specifically requested input until the next line.  It looks at its buffer and says okay, I still have a line separator in my buffer, I don't need to read from the input stream yet.  It consumes the `\R` from its buffer and returns a blank string to you (and you store that blank string in the `nameS` variable).

This pattern continues for the rest of your nextInt-nextLine pairs.  You need to make the scanner read from the input stream by consuming the line separator prior to trying to read a string.  This can be done just by inserting an extra call to `input.nextLine()` each time.  See my modified code:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int S = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
String nameS = input.nextLine();

int P = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
String nameP = input.nextLine();

int E = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
String nameE = input.nextLine();
```

2. You close the scanner after reading from it.  This closes the underlying stream, which is the standard input stream.  This is just bad practice, because then your program can never read from that stream again.  You can't re-open the standard input stream.  Standard practice is just to leave it open, because it will be closed automatically when the JRE terminates.  This does not apply to other streams, so do be careful.
3. You should follow standard naming conventions, so local variables start with a lowercase letter.
4. Your code is somewhat unclear with all of those `>=` down in the if statements.  I think this would be a much cleaner way to do it:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int s = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
String nameS = input.nextLine();

int p = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
String nameP = input.nextLine();

int e = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
String nameE = input.nextLine();

int maxValue = Math.max(s, Math.max(p, e));

if (s == maxValue) {
    System.out.println(nameS);
} else if (p == maxValue) {
    System.out.println(nameP);
} else {
    System.out.println(nameE);
}
```